# Screen Hierarchy

Tags: information-architecture, information, flowcharts

What is a screen hierarchy? We have begun a project in which I need to create a screen hierarchy of the current state of the application, but unclear on what this exactly means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet you saw it many times. Just take a look:

[image]

[source](http://www.yokogawa.com/ns/support/onepoint/utup/ns-onepoint-utup01.htm)

I think you are supposed to develop something like the following:

[image]

[source](https://scs.senecac.on.ca/~prj666/bob/web-site/hierarchy.html)

Answer (score 0):

A sitemap is some high-level overview over your application. Could describe the hierarchy of the system. "How is the app tight together?" You could also design some detailed flow-charts were (parts) of your screens are illustrated and show how you will go from 1 state into the other.

It could also mean "okay what are the regions aka basic blocks of you screen" Let say you're working on Spotify; the left-side radio-stations, playlist have a hierarchical different meaning then a song in the center of your screen. So I could say the left-side has another hierarchical meaning. They are containers for songs if that isn't hierarchy I don't know what is (currently listing Spotify). So you might ask for what he/she/they are looking for. Ask me lad.

EDIT: now I see it's a really old topic. whatever.....